# Issue with base class that gets extended by both Models and Controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, models, controllers

I've got a question regarding a conflict / conundrum I've run into with my application.

I want to make some common "stuff" available to all of my models and controllers, such as data from a cache, or session information, as well as the methods of my PDO wrapper.

Currently each individual feature controller and feature model extends a base controller and base model, which in turn extend a single object that does all of that common stuff.

A controller will get called by a router/dispatcher, and the controller will then call on a model to get some data. The problem with this is it means the main Object gets constructed twice: once when the feature controller is called, and again when the feature controller calls the feature model.

See the diagram below:

[image: How my MVC app is currently structured]

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, so I was wondering if there's some kind of best practice solution to this issue.

What I *dont* want is to have to pass the stuff the object loads, through the controller, to the model. That means any time I have to add a new common element to Object, I have to pass it through to the Model.

It's far simpler and easier for $this->cache or $this->db or $this->session to always be universally available in both controllers and models (as well as future helpers and misc classes).

How would I go about solving this issue?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going in a wrong path about solving this issue.
If you are building an MVC application, you should separate concerns, thats why we use MVC. To separate Models, Controllers and Views.

You should define what do you need Model to do, what will Controller do, and use View only for presentation logic.

In proper MVC, Model is a layer that deals with business logic, database access, validation etc. So Model is not a one class. And you can use many models in one controller. And Controller is just... connection between Models and Views. Models should be fat, and Controllers should be light.

The way you are doing this is in my opinion wrong, since you can do the same stuff in both model and controller and that is not what MVC is for. Controller should not do any logic, thats why we use Models, controller only tells models what to do, and based on their reaction we tell other Models to do something else, or render View with success or error message or with posts from database etc.

The way you can do this is to once you have invoked appropriate controller, use it to get models you need. And again, model is composed of lots of classes, so your model folder can be fat. From Controller you should have only methods to access models so that models can do some actions, and report back to Controller what they did. And based on that returned value you do some more actions or call View to render.

So you should not have one object that can be extended by both models and controllers.

Your model folder can look like this:

```
Models
    - Entities
    - Forms
    - Validators
    - Services
    ...
```

And then you call any of them in your controller to do some action, and report back.
If you really need to have the same functionality in both controllers and models then this didnt answer your question, but I think its wrong to do it like you started.

Hope this helps you, interesting question Il try to help some more if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I get a feeling, that the root of your problems is bad architecture.

The main thing you have to understand about MVC and MVC-inspired design patterns is that the pattern is made from two layers: presentation later and model layer. Those layers should not share common functionality. Controllers (as well as views and templates) are part of presentation layer.

When you have variables like `$this->cache`, `$this->db` or `$this->session` in the controller, it means that you have a severe leak of abstraction. These are storage structures, which should be hidden fairly deep in the model layer. If your controller is interaction with them directly, you do not have a controller.

Next problem is your base class *(the one you call `Object` for some reason .. while objects kinda are instances of a class)*. It seems to be responsible for quite a lot, especially the instantiation of different abstraction for interaction with storage. If you controller needs a PDO instance *(for some exceptionally bizarre reason)*, then it should be injected in the constructor. Same goes for cache and session management.

And then there is that small thing that model is not an object or a class. It is a layer. And just like presentation layer it is composed from different kinds of structures. Usually the recommendation is to have:

- structures that deal with logical entities, which is usually what [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) are for
- one or more types of storage abstractions: [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), [dao](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) and/or some similar structures.
- something, that controls the interaction between the above mentioned structures so that they do not leak in the presentation layer, commonly referred as [services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29)

And yes, you are correct assuming that using controller to pass along structures is a bad practice. It violates [LoD](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter). Instead you should be providing your controller with a factory, that instantiates your model layer structures and provides them with necessary dependencies .. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739161/727208) might help.

> <sub>*my two cents on the subject .. for a more precise advice you would have to show some code*</sub>